# Как использовать Node.js в проекте ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, gulp, node.js

Подскажите примеры подключения различных сборок JavaScript, которые могут быть полезны при разработке Asp.Net приложения в Visual Studio.
Как их прикручивать?
Хотя может всё можно реализовать без JavaScript- интересна именно совместная работа пакетов JavaScript с проектом Visual Studio. 
Как инструмент совместной работы сейчас нашёл расширение NuGet- Microsoft Edje, через которое можно "вшить" функции Asp.Net в Node.js и наоборот. 
И ещё вопрос, так как только начал изучать тему- так и не понял про всякие там Gulp,Grunt, Browserify и т.д.- как это всё прикрутить?